# Difference between subroutine , co-routine , function and thread?

Tags: terminology

I have been reading the Art of Programming, vol 1, for the past 2 days.

There is a topic about subroutine and coroutine.
I am confused. I can't understand when the book says that coroutines are initialised later after main(), unlike subroutines. Furthermore, the invoked coroutine becomes a subroutine for a calling coroutine.

I tried researching over previously asked question on here, where I came to know notions of functions and thread too, in the same context.
The book gives an example about a coroutine using the MIX computer model.
Can I get any simple pseudocode, using an example about coroutines and other terminologies in the context of today's high level languages?

So, a related question: How to differ a subroutine, coroutine, function and thread?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Until we get a post from someone who really knows, here's my understanding to the question, FWIW.

A subroutine and a function are essentially the same thing, with one difference: A function returns some sort of value (usually via the stack or CPU register), while a subroutine does not. Whether subroutine or function, it is a block of executable code, having exactly one point of entry. A co-routine is also a block of executable code, and, just like a subroutine, it has one point of entry. However, it also has one or more points of re-entry. More on this later.

Before getting to threads, let's review: A computer program, also known as a process, will generally have its allocation of memory organized into a code space, a heap, and a stack. The code space stores the one or more blocks of its executable code. The stack stores the parameters, automatic variables, and return addresses of subroutines, functions, and co-routines (and other things too). The heap is the wide-open memory space available to the process for whatever its purposes. In addition to these memory spaces are the CPU registers, each of which stores a set of bits. These bits could be an integer value, a memory address, a bunch of status flags, or whatever. Most programmers don't need to know much about them, but they're there and essential to the operation of the CPU. Probably the ones worth knowing about are the Program Counter, Stack Pointer, and Status Register, but we're not going to get into them here.

A thread is a single logical flow of execution. In a primitive computing system, there is only one thread available to a process. In modern computing systems, a process is composed of one or more threads. Each thread gets its own stack and set of CPU registers (which is usually physically impossible, but made virtual logically  - a detail we'll skip on here). However, while each thread of a process has its own stack and registers, they will all share the same heap and code space. They are also (presumably) running simultaneously; something that can truly happen in a multi-core CPU. So two or more parts of your program can run at the same time.

Back to the co-routine: As mentioned before, it has one or more points of re-entry. A point of re-entry means that the co-routine can allow for some other block of code outside of itself to have some execution time, and then at some future time have execution time resume back within its own block of code. This implies that the parameters and automatic variables of the co-routine are preserved (and restored if need be) whenever execution is yielded to an external block of code and then returns to that of the co-routine. A co-routine is something that is not directly implemented in every programming language, although it is common to many assembly languages. In any case, it is possible to implement a co-routine in a conceptual way. There is a good article on co-routines at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine.

It seems to me there are two principal motivations in implementing a co-routine design pattern: (1) overcoming the limitations of a single-threaded process; and (2) hoping to achieve better computational performance. Motivation (1) is clear to understand when the process must address many things at once where a single thread is a must. Motivation (2) may not be as clear to understand, since that is tied to a lot of particulars about the system hardware, compiler design, and language design. I can only imagine that computational effort might be reduced by cutting-back on stack manipulations, avoidance of redoing intializations in a subroutine, or relieving some of the overhead of maintaining a multi-threaded process.

HTH

Comment: co-routines are also the basis for [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) in Python for example. Effectively building an iterable of length N with space complexity O(1).

Answer (score 44):

Focusing on coroutine vs subroutine:

Coroutines can *yield* and this is interesting.

Yield 'remembers' where the co-routine is so when it is called again it will continue where it left off.

For example:

```
  coroutine foo {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
  }
  print foo();
  print foo();
  print foo();
```

Prints:
1 2 3

Note: Coroutines may use a return, and behave just like a subroutine

```
  coroutine foo {
    return 1;
    return 2; //Dead code
    return 3;
  }
  print foo();
  print foo();
  print foo();
```

Prints:
1 1 1

Comment: As always, examples are worth more than thousand words :)

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to expand on existing answers, adding following:
There exist 4 main concepts in an invocation of a piece of code:

1. creation of a context  (aka "frame", a local environment for this code to operate)
2. resuming/invocation of a context (transferring control to that frame, aka jumping)
3. detaching (resuming another context, similar to 2.)
4. and destruction of a context

In subroutines creation and resuming happen simultaneously with a "call" instruction - a stack frame gets allocated, arguments and return address are pushed, the execution jumps to the piece of called code. Also, detaching (resuming a caller) and destruction are done simultaneously with a "return" instruction - stack frame is de-allocated, control is transferred to a caller (via previously supplied return address) and the caller is left to scavage the junk on a stack to pick out the return value (depending on your calling conventions).
In coroutines, these main concepts exist independently, decoupled from each other. You create a coroutine at some time, then you can transfer control to it later (so it can yield you some results, possibly multiple times), and then you can destroy it at some later point in time.

Comment: In co routines , can we skip statements in next call?

Comment: @Softxide which statements of which call? :) You mean execute a different code after a coroutine was re-invoked? Yes. They keep state inbetween invocations, because context is not destroyed upon detaching.

Answer (score 3):

Differences:
(1) Co-routine doesn't have a master-slave relationship while subroutine has.
(2) A subroutine has a single entry point, while co-routine may have multiple entry points.
(3) The calling program is suspended during execution of the called subroutine. Co-routines provide quasi-concurrent execution.
Similarities:
(1) Both co-routines and subroutines are able to use return.
(2) The execution of both co-routines and subroutines are not overlapped.

Answer (score 2):

Coroutines are simply concurrent subroutines(functions, methods,closures) that are non preemptive.That is they cannot be interrupted,instead coroutines have multiple points thoughout which allows multiple points of suspension or scope reentry.

> Coroutines, are  implicitly  concurrent  constructs,  but  concurrency is not a property of a coroutine: something must host several coroutines simultaneously  and  give  each  an  opportunity  to  execute otherwise,  they  wouldn’t  be concurrent! Note that this does not imply that coroutines are implicitly parallel.

Comment: Goroutines are coroutines

Answer (score 2):

from python docs,

> Coroutines are a more generalized form of subroutines. Subroutines are entered at one point and exited at another point. Coroutines can be entered, exited, and resumed at many different points. They can be implemented with the async def statement.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward explanation that I found about the difference between subroutine and coroutine is that a coroutine keeps “state” between calls.

In other words a coroutine can store values between calls, and retrieve them when you call it again, while a subroutine always starts its values from the “beginning”.